# Итерирование по словарю по парам ключ, значение в Питоне

Tags: python

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно проитерироваться по словарю, то есть по парам (ключ, значение)?

Что-нибудь вроде:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
for key, value in ???:
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 5):

`for key, value in d.items(): ...`

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: по-моему это наиболее правильный (идиоматический) вариант +1

Answer (score 1):

Есть два варианта.
Итерация по ключу и выдергивание значения по этому ключу:

```
for key in d:
    print key, d[key]
```

И есть вариант с iteritems (Python 2.x как верно подсказывают):

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Comment: В третьем питоне нет iteritems

Comment: @andreymal на версию питона намекает разве что способ вызова print у автора, но так можно и во втором.

Comment: Во втором такой принт вместо двух элементов, разделённых пробелами, отпечатает кортеж :)

Comment: @andreymal остается только гадать что именно хотел автор и какая у него версия :-D

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
for key in d: # Цикл for по умолчанию идет по ключам 
    print(key, d[key])
for key, val in d.items(): # проход по парам
    print(key, val)
```

Comment: Это с циклом)))

Answer (score 0):

Одновременно положить в отдельные переменные ключ и значение у словаря невозможно, стандартный вариант это:

```
for key in myDict:
    print(myDict[key])
```

Но мы отлично можем сделать это итерируя по списку кортежей, где мы можем положить в отдельную переменную каждый элемент кортежа:

```
L = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

for first, second in L:
    print(first, second)
```

У словарей есть метод `items` который превращает словарь в генератор по интерфейсу схожий с списком кортежей которые хранят в себе два элемента, первый это ключ словаря, а второй его значение, а как мы видим из примера выше мы легко можем воспользоваться этим во время итераций:

```
myDict = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}

for key, value in myDict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Comment: `items()` - просто возвращает итератор (по сути то что в Python 2 называлось [Dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)), а не превращает словарь в список кортежей. И почему-то мне кажется, что возможность использования `items()` опровергает утверждение в начале ответа "Одновременно положить в отдельные переменные ключ и значение у словаря невозможно".

Comment: @insolor я имел ввиду без использования методов, которые превращают словарь в другой тип данных, а за замечание спасибо, почему то у меня все время в голове сидело, что `items` именно в список кортежей превращает.

Comment: Преобразования данных тоже нет, кстати, это просто тонкая прослойка ("view") над словарем: при изменении исходного словаря (в том числе и в процессе итерации) меняется и items.

Comment: @insolor ясно, буду знать.

Comment: В python3 есть возможность итерации `for item in d.items()`, где `item` будет кортежем вида `(key, value)`

Comment: @Yaroslav Surzhikov я именно про это и написал